# Artifact publish fails sometimes (random) in matrix strategy build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I recently started using Azure DevOps to deploy applications to Azure services and so far I like what I'm seeing.

The only issue I don't seem to solve is that when I use a **matrix strategy** to run my fast running tests, I end up with **random amount of failures publishing my artifacts** which **causes the build to fail**.

[image: Build failed because 2 out of 4 strategies were not able to publish]

When opening up the detail of the error it states that **Blob was incomplete**, here's a snippet from the full detail.

```sh
Uploading 1 files
Uploading 'drop/18.zip' (16%)
Uploading 'drop/18.zip' (33%)
Uploading 'drop/18.zip' (50%)
Uploading 'drop/18.zip' (66%)
Uploading 'drop/18.zip' (83%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Fail to upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a/18.zip' due to 'Blob is incomplete (missing block). Blob: c2569a8734a4e911bcd10003ffded5ab, Expected Offset: 0, Actual Offset: 8388608'.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Blob is incomplete (missing block).
```

Since the build process runs on the DevOps infrastructure I haven't figured out how to debug this step. At this point I can run my builds successful when not using the matrix strategy and using a single version strategy.

Is this a known problem with Azure DevOps and is there a way to fix this issue?

This is a public project, you can have a look at https://dev.azure.com/In2itvof/AzureBlob/_build/results?buildId=18 to see the errors.

Here's a snippet from my `azure-pipelines.yml` configuration. You can see the full source code at [GitHub/DragonBe/AzureBlob](https://github.com/DragonBe/AzureBlob).

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    php71:
      php_version: "7.1"
    php72:
      php_version: "7.2"
    php73:
      php_version: "7.3"
    php74:
      php_version: "7.4"
  maxParallel: 4
```

In between I run my tests and publish their results

```
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

So the issue is that it can not properly publish the artifacts because of an internal failure. Anyone has experienced the same issue or has found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Look like a bug, try to create an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21

Answer (score 0):

We hit this in our build when two concurrent legs of the build were trying to upload the same asset.  You might want to check if that's what's happening here.